# Can i use the coefficients of a trained model of Logistic Regression as a result itself without using the model on unseen data?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, data-analysis

I'm trying to figure out if i can use a logistic regression as a predictive model, to estimate the probability of response of a user in CRM by having the predictors and i also have the class (detractor, not detractor) but the thing is that i don't want to estimate the probability of detraction since i already know the detractors, i already have the class and i'm always going to have it. What i was thinking was to train the model, use the probability given the predictors and then study the behavior of coefficients to know how this affects the probability. I will get the data periodically but is always going to have the class, so would it be ok to train the model everytime we get the data labeled (since we are going to make decisions everytime we train the model data should change and also the coefficients) and the results be the value of coefficients and influence in probability without having to apply a model on not seen data?

Basically i want to know if this is valid in a statistical sense and also if this could be a good result to business, since what they want to know is how the independent variables that we capture, affect the result of a client saying that they will not recommend the use of the product.

Thanks so much in advanced guys, sorry if i'm saying silly things, i'm not an expert in data science yet. Just starting.

Comment: Apart from rather unclear, this is certainly not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here. *Maybe* suitable for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

You can get some idea by looking at the coefficients if you normalize them. The normalized value of the coefficients will then tell you how strongly the factor affects your target variable as compared to other factors